# How to fit a paragraph inside a css polygon

Tags: html, css

I have been able to successfully use `shape-outside: polygon(...)` and `clip-path: polygon(...)` to create a desired polygon shape.

I have seen many pages referencing use of `shape-inside`, and yet I have read that `shape-inside` had been deprecated and has no replacement. They were also written in 2014, so I am hoping that CSS3 has changed since then.

After looking on the web, I was able to piece together something that *almost* works. I like the shape, but now I need the text wrap inside the shape with the overflow hidden.

I have seen hints about `::before`, but I still don't understand how that would help. Testing it didn't seem to produce any results.

Whether it's simple or complicated, how can I use CSS to wrap the text within the polygon? Or does the solution lie outside of CSS? Do I need to use another approach, like jQuery?

[image: This is the polygon with text clipped off.]

**CSS**

```
/*
For reference:    
@vertex1: 120px;
@vertex2: @vertex1*2;
*/

.diamondContainer {
    display: block;    
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: @vertex2;
    height: @vertex2;
    overflow: hidden; /* hide anything longer than allowed string length */

    /* This is a diamond shape */    
    shape-outside: polygon(@vertex1 0, @vertex2 @vertex1, @vertex1 @vertex2, 0 @vertex1);    
    clip-path: polygon(@vertex1 0, @vertex2 @vertex1, @vertex1 @vertex2, 0 @vertex1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="diamondOuter">
    <div class="diamondWrapper">
        <div class="diamondContainer diamondCell2">
            <span><strong>Title Text</strong><br />Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look again at `shape-outside`.

You don't set it on the text container, but other elements around the text.

In your case, you may need to have at least 2 `div`'s for the text to flow around.

There is an example of text flowing between 2 `polygon`s on this page.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

[image]

Comment: This helped. I had to re-think my paradigm, using the left and right divs like molds.

Comment: glad to help. pls don't forget to mark your question answered :D